# Date validation using JavaScript ( how can a discharge date always be greater than the admission date)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an admission date and a discharge date in my html code. Now can i validate the dates such that the discharge date is always greater than the admission date? I would be very thankful if anyone likes to help me.

Here is the html and JavaScript code for the same:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
    }
  });
  $("#txtToDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
Admission Date:<input type="date" name="admission_dt" id="txtFromDate" required/> 
Discharge Date:<input type="date" name="discharge_dt" id="txtToDate" required/>
```

Comment: Here is the html and JavaScript code for the same:

Comment: <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
                    numberOfMonths: 2,
                    onSelect: function(selected) {
                        $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
                    }});
                $("#txtToDate").datepicker({
                    numberOfMonths: 2,
                    onSelect: function(selected) {
                        $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
                    }
             });
            }); </script>

Comment: Admission Date:<input type="date" name="admission_dt" id="txtFromDate" required/>             Discharge Date:<input type="date" name="discharge_dt" id="txtToDate" required/>

Comment: Why don't to use datepicker in [date-range](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#date-range) mode?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const admissionDate = new Date('2016-01-01');
const dischargeDate = new Date('2017-01-01');

function isDischargeGreaterThanAdmission(admissionDate, dischargeDate){
 return dischargeDate > admissionDate;
}

console.log(isDischargeGreaterThanAdmission(admissionDate, dischargeDate));
```

Comment: Where do we need to type in this code in <script></script> ?